# Sending SMS via AT commands using GSM/LTE module responds Ok but no SMS received

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, lte, quectel

I'm attempting to send and receive SMS via my GSM/LTE module (EC21 Quectel) using AT commands in my ubuntu terminal. However, all my messages return OK after being sent but do not reach their respective locations.

```
AT
OK
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGW="+1XXXXXXXXXX"
> test 4
+CMGW: 13

OK
AT+CMSS=13
+CMSS: 39

OK
AT+CMGS="+1XXXXXXXXXX"
> test 5
+CMGS: 40

OK
```

---

In terminal, I did use sudo screen and the correct baud rate of 115200 per documentation. Here's some additional info

```
AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+CGREG?
+CGREG: 0,1

OK
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"AT&T",7

OK
AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 31,99
```

Answer (score 2):

If the SMS send command succeeds, and it's not received, I can figure out only three causes:

1. (unlikely) there's a bug in Quectel module
2. There's a newtork congestion. In this case the SMS will be received, soon or later.
3. Some issues on receiver side. For example full SM memory